# How to change $httpBackend when[method] statements between requests in unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In my testing i initiate some model data and mock the response:

```
beforeEach(function(){
   var re = new RegExp(/^http\:\/\/.+?\/users-online\/(.+)$/);
   $httpBackend.whenGET(re).respond({id:12345, usersOnline:5000});
});      

it('should find 5000 users in channel 12345', function(){
    expect( UsersOnlineService.data.usersOnline).toEqual( 50000);
});
```

then say in the next test statement i want the updated value for the channel. Everyone has left, and hypothetically this would trigger other behavior, so i need to mock this second request so i can test that behavioer.

Adding the `$httpBackend.whenGET` to the next `it` statment does not override the `beforeEach` value. It seems to use the original mock value:

```
it('should find 0 users in channel 12345', function(){
    $httpBackend.whenGET(re).respond({id:12345, usersOnline:0});
    expect( UsersOnlineService.data.usersOnline).toEqual( 50000); //fails
});
```

And if I do it like this without the beforeEach, both fail with the usual "unexpectedGet" error.

```
it('should find 5000 users in channel 12345', function(){
     var re = new RegExp(/^http\:\/\/.+?\/users-online\/(.+)$/);
     $httpBackend.whenGET(re).respond({id:12345, usersOnline:5000});
    expect( UsersOnlineService.data.usersOnline).toEqual( 50000); //fails
});

it('should find 0 users in channel 12345', function(){
      var re = new RegExp(/^http\:\/\/.+?\/users-online\/(.+)$/);
     $httpBackend.whenGET(re).respond({id:12345, usersOnline:0});
    expect( UsersOnlineService.data.usersOnline).toEqual( 0); //fails
});
```

How to modulate mock data between requests?

I also tried:

- sandwiching a `beforeEach` between `it` statements
- setting a `.respond(` to a `fakeResponse` variable. Then changing the `fakeResponse` value in each `it` statement.

Comment: I don't see anything that make a http request. You have to setup the `$httpBackend` before the request is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### resetExpectations()

Execution

```
afterEach($httpBackend.resetExpectations);
```

Documentation

> Resets all request expectations, but preserves all backend definitions. Typically, you would call resetExpectations during a multiple-phase test when you want to reuse the same instance of $httpBackend mock.

documentation source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: Ah, I had tried this at some point, then I realized I needed to use expect('GET',regex).respond() isntead of whenGET(...)

Comment: Actually, i tricked myself into thinking this worked. I'm still not having luck. I made a new question with an example jsFiddle now that I have more knowledge of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370273/how-to-actually-reset-httpbackend-expectations